# Probability Over Time With Deck of Cards

Tags: probability

o Given say, a deck of cards, I draw cards until I pick out a specific one, in this case, the Ace of Spades. What is the probability that I picked the ace of spades last of out all 52 cards. And by extension, what is the probability that I picked the Ace of Spades in any given position (i.e. 32nd, 43rd), that is to say, are the odds the same that I picked the Ace of Spades 32nd with the odds that I picked it 43rd (Assuming no replacement)?

Would one way of doing this be to calculate total number of ways a 52-card deck could be shuffled and then determine the number of times the Ace of Spades is in any one position?

Answer (score 1):

> Would one way of doing this be to calculate total number of ways a 52-card deck could be shuffled and then determine the number of times the Ace of Spades is in any given position?

Yes.  That is One the way to do it.

Another is that each card has the *same* probability of being in that position, and there are 52 cards.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of picking a particular card at any position is $1/52$.  Notice that selecting an Ace of Spades last is equal to the probability that the card at the bottom of the deck is the Ace of Spades.  For any other position, you can simply remove all the cards above that position and move them to the bottom of the deck.  There are $52$ cards in the deck.  The probability that the card now at the top of the deck is the Ace of Spades is $1/52$.